# How can I get subList of a List in Apex Salesforce?

Tags: list, salesforce, apex-code, apex, sublist

I have got a list of SObjects having N number of items/sObjects
 SObject[] sList = [sobject1, sboject2, sboject3, ........ , sobjectN]

How can I get just 10 items from the begining of the list

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After running this code `newList` contains only first 10 objects from `sList`.

```
SObject[] sList = [sobject1, sboject2, sboject3, ... , sobjectN];
List<SObject> newList = new List<SObject>();

for (Integer i = 0; i< 10; i++) {
    newList.add(sList[i]);
}
```

For more info please reffer to [List documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_list.htm#apex_System_List_methods)

Answer (score 0):

I also thought of using while and remove method:

```
SObject[] sList = [object1, object2,...];
if(sList.size() >= 10){
  while(sList.size() > 10){
    sList.remove(sList.size() - 1);
  }
}
System.debug('values: '+sList);
```